# RewriteRule htaccess delete url parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can i delete the URL parameter ID from the URL?
I have a new cms with the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?id=$1&titel=$2
```

Domain Output:
domain.de/13/pagename/

Now i want to change the URl output to:
domain.de/pagename

Is that possible only with the rewrite rules?

Comment: Is "13" the ID you are using to look up your page?

Comment: "13" is the page id. Every page has a own id. I only can see the page with index.php?id=13&titel=pagename | index.php?titel=pagename does not work.

Comment: You can rewrite the URL to `domain.de/pagename` but then your script won't know which page to look up any more. Either you change your script so it can look up the page using `pagename`, or you need to stick with the 13

Comment: Is it also possible only to get the id in the htacces and make a new url manuell?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify? What URL should the user enter?

Comment: Now i have the url: domain.de/13/pagename
But I want the url: domain.de/13/pagename

Is that possible without changing the script? Maybe only a RewriteRule which change the url domain.de/13/pagename to domain.de/pagename. The Page has only 5 Sites if it's possible i can write the urls manuell in the htacces ;)

Comment: OK and what do you want the user to enter in the future?

Comment: In the future the user enter domain.de/pagename

Comment: Well, then you'll have to make the receiving script be able to find the right page using `titel` only, no? How should the .htaccess file know that `pagename` translates to `13`?

Comment: Now the script search the id and take the pagename of the page. Also i have to make the script be able to find the page using the titel or?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure I would do that though, at least not for search engine optimization reasons. Stack Overflow uses the `/id/pagename` scheme and they do excellently well in Google.

Comment: Yeah thats right. But i think the id is only good when you have a news section, blog section or question like that. But when you only have 5 static sites it's not so good.